# What is the pattern in this series: $\frac{r}{2} + \frac{4r^2}{9} + \frac{9r^3}{28} + \frac{16r^4}{65} + \dotsb$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

A book gave me the following series, and asked for which $r\in \mathbb{R}$ does it converge:

$$\frac{r}{2} + \frac{4r^2}{9} + \frac{9r^3}{28} + \frac{16r^4}{65} + \dotsb$$

I feel dumb because I can't even find the pattern in the denominator! It's not arithmetic (adding 7, then adding 19, then adding 37), looking at the prime factors doesn't seem to help ($2$, $3\cdot3$, $2\cdot2\cdot7$, $5\cdot 13$). Can someone see it?

Sorry, I'm sure it's obvious and I'm just missing it.

Comment: I hate to be "overly technical to the point it is useless" but this book needs to give additional clues: for example that the numerator and denominator are polynomials or something along those lines. Since technically this could be any pattern that starts with those terms and therefore is a poor question (not your fault! The books fault!)

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: No other clues are necessary: in problems of this kind there is a tacit assumption that the general term has a reasonable nice description. Students should of course learn at some point that a finite initial segment does nothing to determine an infinite sequence, but at this stage it’s much more important that they be able to spot simple numerical patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general term of the series is
$$a_n=\frac {n^2r^n}{n^3+1}\sim_\infty \frac {r^n}{n}$$
so by the ratio test the Radius of convergence of the serie is $R=1$ and for $r=-1$ we can show that the series is convergent by the alternating test and it's a divergent series at $r=1$ and finally the interval of convergence is $[-1,1)$.

Comment: I answered the question of the book.

Comment: Well I respect your opinion even though the comment seems to contain a mockery but do I have to answer exactly the question and I do not have the right to add what seems to me useful for the reader?

Answer (score 11):

In the denominator, you want $$9=2^3+1$$ $$28=3^3+1$$  $$65=4^3+1$$

Thus, the general term is $$x_n=\frac{n^2}{n^3+1}r^n$$

Comment: Nice answer! Literally!